# PhoneGap issue in ios 7 (alter image size not working)

Tags: image, cordova, ios7

I recently upgraded my iphone from ios 6 to ios 7 since then when i deploy my  phonegap application its getting alignment issue in ios 7(images are getting oversized). This was working perfectly in ios 6 but in ios 7 getting this issue.I am using cordova 2.2 and xcode 5 in mavericks.Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: i have tried. it dint solve my problem.please can you say any other solution?